# Adding a password field to my form makes jquery unable to detect :focus button on ajax:error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm POSTing a new record to the database via ajax. My form looks like this:

*Note: This is using Rails helpers + SLIM language*

```
=form_for User.new, remote: true, method: :post, html:{role:'form'} do |f|
  =f.text_field :username
  =f.text_field :email

  =f.submit 'Create',class:'btn',data:{feedback:'#feedback-location'}
  #feedback-location
```

I want to add a spinner on `ajax:before` event and a message on `ajax:after`. I do so like this:

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'ajax:before', ->
    clicked = $(':focus')
    location = $(clicked).data 'feedback'
    add_spinner location

  $(document).on 'ajax:error', ->
    clicked = $(':focus')
    location = $(clicked).data 'feedback'
    add_msg location
    // do other things
```

I use `$(':focus')` since at the same time there can be more than one very similar forms activated and I want to **detect** the one that was clicked.

All this works wonderfully and the variable `clicked` is assigned with the proper DOM element that was clicked ( submit button).

**However...**

Whenever I append to my form a *password* field, the same Javascript code fails to **detect** the focused/clicked submit button at the `ajax:error` event. ie.`clicked = *undefined*`

```
=form_for User.new, remote: true, method: :post, html:{role:'form'} do |f|
  =f.text_field :username
  =f.text_field :email
  =f.password_field :password #<---------Appended

  =f.submit 'Create',class:'btn',data:{feedback:'#feedback-location'}
  #feedback-location
```

Any ideas why this happens?

ps. It would be so cool to have syntax highlighting for slim/jade/haml and coffeescript.

Comment: I suggest that when ajax:error is triggered there is no focussed elements. Ajax is asynchronous. On ajax:before focus exists and when request is finished it may not

Comment: However, when at the `ajax:error` *without* the password field, the focused element *is* there. How weird is that?

Comment: May be it is a browser feature that it automatically disables focus if password field is submitted ( for some security reason)

Comment: That's a reasonable hypothesis, I was thinking something similar. It would just be nice to have someone confirming it